# Why constructor is not being called?

Tags: java

In http://www.javatpoint.com/constructor, it says "Method name may or may not be same as class name." So I just created this program to test it out. However its calling the "Constructor" method. Why is it calling the method ?

```
public class Constructor {
    // default constructor
    Constructor(){}

    // paramterized constructor
    Constructor(int a){System.out.println("Constructor called");}

    static Constructor Constructor(int a){
        System.out.println("Method called");
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Constructor c = Constructor(5);
    }
}
```

I always thought creating an object called its constructor.

```
Constructor c = Constructor(5);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Constructor c = Constructor(5);` it's calling `Constructor()` method because there's no `new` used.

If you do `Constructor c = new Constructor(5);`, it will call the class constructor.